# Apache FOP losing elements

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop, jdom

I'm trying to print a PDF using Apache FOP + XSL as follow:

(`in` is JDOM)

```
private void transformPDF(Document in, StreamSource template, OutputStream out) throws ConvertirXMLException {

try {

    Driver driver = new Driver();
    driver.setOutputStream(out);
    driver.setRenderer(1);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(template);

    transformer.transform(new JDOMSource(in), new SAXResult(driver.getContentHandler()));

} catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConvertirXMLException(e.toString());
    }

}
```

It's like FOP's documentation but it's not working fine. If I go to debug mode, i can see that in has the correct content, but when FOP transform the data to PDF, I lose some elements.

I have tested the in data and my template in a XSL editor where you can debug it and make some transformations and works fine (no lose data) so I'm a little bit lost... Any idea?

Comment: Does your XSL contain templates for the elements missing in the output?

Comment: Yes, but too for the no missing elements

Comment: Is the content missing from the FO file too, or just from the resulting PDF? Do you get any warning message from FOP (not-yet-implemented features, ...)?

Comment: No, I have no warnings or errors... And just from the resulting PDF. Apparently the XSL-FO is OK. I'm thinking about a problem with fop.jar versions (My project have one, but I think that the server can have another one). It's possible that's a problem?

Comment: (1) which version of FOP are you using? If I remember correctly, the `Driver` class was used a long _long_ time ago.  (2) can you edit your question to include an example of FO element that "disappears" from the PDF output?

Comment: Solved, it was a version problem... I changed Driver to Transformer and I have updated libraries versions. I have changed too the strictMode to false for some errors that I can't solve because the template must be used with old versions of FOP too... Now the PDF is printed perfectly. Thank you so much!